# Font whitespace not rendered correctly?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a font in Unity that has a custom whitespace, namely a bar above and below an empty space. Outside Unity it works perfectly fine, but inside Unity the whitespace is not rendered properly.

This is how it looks inside of Unity:

[image: This is how it looks inside of Unity]

This is how it looks outside of Unity:

[image: This is how it looks outside of Unity]

Does anyone know of a way to fix it? I am running Unity on Linux, but I confirmed that this behavior also exists on Windows.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: I suspect that Unity (by default--see vmchar's answer) assumes that all spaces are, in fact, empty whitespace (even when they're not). You can also go about rendering the font yourself (I wrote a font renderer in Unity once, it probably wasn't very good, but it was an interesting experience).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using UnityUI to renderer this, you should keep in mind that it has a lot of troubles with custom fonts. Consider using [TextMeshPro](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/84126) for this purposes, it's developed by Unity itself, free and working better with fonts